# Flutter - Drag Animation is not returning to the start after ListView update

Tags: dart, flutter

The animation of `ListView` items that is about dragging to the left and the delete button appears works fine. The problem is that if I leave the delete button appearing and changing the page, when I return `pop()` to the previous page the button keeps appearing.

The animation did not go back to the beginning. The same happens if I update the items in the `ListView`, for example deleting an item. The item is deleted but the animation is not.

It looks like I'm updating the `ListView` content and not the `ListView` itself.

How could you solve this problem?

I'm trying to destroy `ListView` with every update in its items, but I'm not getting it. I also do not know if this is the right way to solve the problem.

The `ListView` is built through the `buildTile()` function and its items come from the database.

Below I put the code and a gif demonstrating what the problem is.

To work the code below, you need to insert the `sqflite` and `path_provider` dependencies into `pubspec.yaml`, thus:

```
dependencies:
  sqflite: any
  path_provider: any
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

enum DialogOptionsAction {
  cancel,
  ok
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/newpage': (BuildContext context) => new NewPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DatabaseClient _db = new DatabaseClient();
  List listCategory = [];
  List<Widget> tiles;

  List colors = [
    const Color(0xFFFFA500),
    const Color(0xFF279605),
    const Color(0xFF005959)
  ];

  createdb() async {
    await _db.create().then(
      (data){
        _db.getAllCategory().then((list){
          setState(() {
            this.listCategory = list;
          });
        });
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createdb();    
  }

  void showCategoryDelete<T>({ BuildContext context, Widget child }) {
    showDialog<T>(
      context: context,
      child: child,
    )
    .then<Null>((T value) {
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() { print(value); });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> buildTile(List list) {
      this.tiles = [];
      for(var dict in list) {
        this.tiles.add(
          new ItemCategory(
            id: dict['id'],
            category: dict['name'],
            color: this.colors[dict['color']],
            onPressed: () async {
              showCategoryDelete<DialogOptionsAction>(
                context: context,
                child: new AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Delete Category'),
                  content: new Text(
                    'Do you want to delete this category?',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black26,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      )
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('OK'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _db.deleteCategory(dict['id']).then(
                          (list) {
                            setState(() {
                              this.listCategory = list;
                            });
                          }
                        );
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    )
                  ]
                )
              );
            },
          )
        );
      }
      return this.tiles;
    }
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Categories'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            onPressed: () async {
              await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/newpage').then(
                (data){
                  _db.getAllCategory().then((list){
                    setState(() {
                      this.listCategory = list;
                    });
                  });
                }
              );
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 0.0, left: 0.0),
        children: buildTile(this.listCategory)
      )
    );
  }
}

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('New Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Creating Database with some data and two queries
class DatabaseClient {
  Database db;

  Future create() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: this._create);
  }

  Future _create(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("""
      CREATE TABLE category (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        color INTEGER NOT NULL
      )""");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo1', 0)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo2', 1)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo3', 2)");
  }

  Future getAllCategory() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    Database db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

    List list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM category');
    await db.close();

    return list;
  }

  Future deleteCategory(int id) async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    Database db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

    await db.delete('category', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    List list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM category');

    await db.close();

    return list;
  }
}

//Creating ListViews items
class ItemCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  ItemCategory({ Key key, this.id, this.category, this.color, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final int id;
  final String category;
  final Color color;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  ItemCategoryState createState() => new ItemCategoryState();
}

class ItemCategoryState extends State<ItemCategory> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  ItemCategoryState();

  DatabaseClient db = new DatabaseClient();
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  double flingOpening;
  bool startFling = true;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(duration: 
      const Duration(milliseconds: 246), vsync: this);

    _animation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: new Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.linear),
    );
  }

  void _move(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final double delta = details.primaryDelta / 304;
    _controller.value -= delta;
  }

  void _settle(DragEndDetails details) {
    if(this.startFling) {
      _controller.fling(velocity: 1.0);
      this.startFling = false;
    } else if(!this.startFling){
      _controller.fling(velocity: -1.0);
      this.startFling = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _width = logicalSize.width;
    this.flingOpening = -(48.0/_width);

    return new GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _move,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _settle,
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Positioned.fill(
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                  ),
                  child: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                    color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    onPressed: widget.onPressed
                  )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new SlideTransition(
            position: new Tween<Offset>(
              begin:  Offset.zero,
              end: new Offset(this.flingOpening, 0.0),
            ).animate(_animation),
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border(
                  top: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black26),
                ),
                color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              ),
              margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0, top: 4.5, bottom: 4.5),
                          child: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                margin: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                                child: new Icon(
                                  Icons.brightness_1,
                                  color: widget.color,
                                  size: 35.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              new Text(
                                widget.category,
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Flutter - Widget animation status remains even after it has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286895/flutter-widget-animation-status-remains-even-after-it-has-been-removed)

Simply insert the key into the new ItemCategory (

I needed to pass a `key` to the children. Or else the renderer won't be able to know which SlideTransition got removed, and use the index.

```
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List<Widget> buildTile(List list) {
    this.tiles = [];
    for(var dict in list) {
      this.tiles.add(
        new ItemCategory(
          key: new Key(dict), //new
          id: dict['id'],
          category: dict['name'],
...
```

[image]

The complete code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

enum DialogOptionsAction {
  cancel,
  ok
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/newpage': (BuildContext context) => new NewPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DatabaseClient _db = new DatabaseClient();
  List listCategory = [];
  List<Widget> tiles;

  List colors = [
    const Color(0xFFFFA500),
    const Color(0xFF279605),
    const Color(0xFF005959)
  ];

  createdb() async {
    await _db.create().then(
      (data){
        _db.getAllCategory().then((list){
          setState(() {
            this.listCategory = list;
          });
        });
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createdb();    
  }

  void showCategoryDelete<T>({ BuildContext context, Widget child }) {
    showDialog<T>(
      context: context,
      child: child,
    )
    .then<Null>((T value) {
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() { print(value); });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> buildTile(List list) {
      this.tiles = [];
      for(var dict in list) {
        this.tiles.add(
          new ItemCategory(
            key: new Key(dict), //new
            id: dict['id'],
            category: dict['name'],
            color: this.colors[dict['color']],
            onPressed: () async {
              showCategoryDelete<DialogOptionsAction>(
                context: context,
                child: new AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Delete Category'),
                  content: new Text(
                    'Do you want to delete this category?',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black26,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      )
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('OK'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _db.deleteCategory(dict['id']).then(
                          (list) {
                            setState(() {
                              this.listCategory = list;
                            });
                          }
                        );
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    )
                  ]
                )
              );
            },
          )
        );
      }
      return this.tiles;
    }
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Categories'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            onPressed: () async {
              await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/newpage').then(
                (data){
                  _db.getAllCategory().then((list){
                    setState(() {
                      this.listCategory = list;
                    });
                  });
                }
              );
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 0.0, left: 0.0),
        children: buildTile(this.listCategory)
      )
    );
  }
}

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('New Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Creating Database with some data and two queries
class DatabaseClient {
  Database db;

  Future create() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: this._create);
  }

  Future _create(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("""
      CREATE TABLE category (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        color INTEGER NOT NULL
      )""");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo1', 0)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo2', 1)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo3', 2)");
  }

  Future getAllCategory() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    Database db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

    List list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM category');
    await db.close();

    return list;
  }

  Future deleteCategory(int id) async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    Database db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

    await db.delete('category', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    List list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM category');

    await db.close();

    return list;
  }
}

//Creating ListViews items
class ItemCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  ItemCategory({ Key key, this.id, this.category, this.color, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final int id;
  final String category;
  final Color color;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  ItemCategoryState createState() => new ItemCategoryState();
}

class ItemCategoryState extends State<ItemCategory> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  ItemCategoryState();

  DatabaseClient db = new DatabaseClient();
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  double flingOpening;
  bool startFling = true;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(duration: 
      const Duration(milliseconds: 246), vsync: this);

    _animation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: new Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.linear),
    );
  }

  void _move(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final double delta = details.primaryDelta / 304;
    _controller.value -= delta;
  }

  void _settle(DragEndDetails details) {
    if(this.startFling) {
      _controller.fling(velocity: 1.0);
      this.startFling = false;
    } else if(!this.startFling){
      _controller.fling(velocity: -1.0);
      this.startFling = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _width = logicalSize.width;
    this.flingOpening = -(48.0/_width);

    return new GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _move,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _settle,
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Positioned.fill(
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                  ),
                  child: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                    color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    onPressed: widget.onPressed
                  )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new SlideTransition(
            position: new Tween<Offset>(
              begin:  Offset.zero,
              end: new Offset(this.flingOpening, 0.0),
            ).animate(_animation),
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border(
                  top: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black26),
                ),
                color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              ),
              margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0, top: 4.5, bottom: 4.5),
                          child: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                margin: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                                child: new Icon(
                                  Icons.brightness_1,
                                  color: widget.color,
                                  size: 35.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              new Text(
                                widget.category,
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```